# Eclipse. Different Workspaces. Can't save same project name

Tags: java, c++, python, eclipse

all. I've read the existing threads on this topic.

My understanding is that if I use different workspaces in Eclipse, I should be able to save the same project name. But I'm not able to and not sure why.

In Windows 7, I have Eclipse Kepler (Java) installed with the C++ and Python plugins. I created three workspaces:

- C:\eclipse\workspace-c++
- C:\eclipse\workspace-java
- C:\eclipse\workspace-python

... and I want to create HelloWorld projects in each. I can create the first project, but when I switch perspective and try to save the second in a different workspace, it says that the "project already exists."

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You said you changed perspective. That's not the same as changing the workspace. If you really want to switch to another workspace, go to "File" -> "Switch Workspace"

Comment: That did it, thanks. When I create the second HelloWorld, I set the new workspace in the dialog; but I guess that is not good enough. Too bad because switching workspaces reboots Eclipse which takes time.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to have Eclipse projects with the same name in different workspaces

Based on your description, it sounds like you may not actually be using multiple workspaces.

The following describes two ways to how start Eclipse in a specific workspace.

To start up eclipse using a specific workspace you can do the following:.

```
eclipse.exe -data c:\path\to\my\workspace_1
```

*`-data` is used to specify the workspace on the eclipse command line*

You can also switch workspaces via `File->Switch Workspace`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be in a hidden working set? In the Project Explorer, expand the menu (downward arrow on top right) and in *Select Working Set*, make sure all working sets are selected.